# Example of a non-trivial TDD grails project with an educational/informative commit history

Tags: grails, tdd

I have made some pretty cool things with grails, but I am still unable to wrap my head around testing.  Is there a public project with a commit history that I can follow which shows good TDD practice?  Ideally some failing tests get committed and then some passing code gets committed, rinse and repeat.

Fantasy preferences:  using git, testing done with spock or easyb or cucumber, has some interesting/hard-to-test plugins like the mail plugin or rabbitMQ.

Comment: I know this is not a direct answer but you can watch this: [link](http://marakana.com/s/techtv_video_series_efficient_rails_test_driven_development_class_1_of_6,191/index.html) and learn how to test all kind of stuff regardless in what language are you working on...